MySQL fetch employee count in the last available month in each year
I have a table with column year, month, employee_count. I want to fetch employee_count from the latest month available in each year
From this:



year
month
employee_count




2010
1
230


2013
6
1205


2022
1
200


2023
1
20


2013
5
123


2010
11
33


2023
10
45



I need this:



year
month
employee_count




2010
11
33


2013
6
1205


2022
1
200


2023
10
45




Based on your description of the issue, and your desired output:

With a subquery (latest_month_per_year) retrieve the latest month (MAX(month)) for each year by grouping the data by year.
And then the main query joins the original table with the subquery on year and month, so that it fetches the row with the latest month for each year.

SELECT t.year, t.month, t.employee_count
FROM employee_table t
JOIN (
    SELECT year, MAX(month) AS latest_month
    FROM employee_table
    GROUP BY year
) AS latest_month_per_year
ON t.year = latest_month_per_year.year AND t.month = latest_month_per_year.latest_month;


As an outcome this will give you the latest employee_count per each year.

I tried the below query with RIGHT JOIN which seems to work:
SELECT B.year, A.month, A.employee_count
FROM 
  EMPLOYEE A 
    RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT MAX(month) as max_month, year
   FROM 
     EMPLOYEE 
   GROUP BY year) B
ON (A.month = B.max_month AND A.year = B.year);

